# Inline Editing of Textarea – How to get the id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use [jqInlineEdit](https://github.com/faulker/jqInlineEdit) for inline editing on a web page. Everything works, except I don't know how to get the `id` of the item which I need for saving the change to the database(via Django).

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="remark14756" class="remark" data-cid="14756">
    Sample Text
</div>
```

That's the JavaScript:

```
<script src="/static/inline-edit.jquery.js"></script>
<script>

    $(".remark").inlineEdit({
        type: 'textarea',

        onChange: function (e, text, html) {
            // Executes when exiting inline edit mode and a change has been made
            c_id = $(this).attr("data-cid");
            alert("Test: ", c_id)
        }
    });
</script>
```

Obviously, `$(this)` does not work in this context. I tried everything and searched a lot but I can't find how to do it the right way. Does anybody know the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [inlineEdit docs](https://github.com/faulker/jqInlineEdit) say:

> *`onChange(this, text, html)` - Executes when exiting inline edit mode and a change has been made*

with the use of `this` being quite misleading.

therefore the first param is actually the Element.

```
$(".remark").inlineEdit({
    type: 'textarea',

    onChange: function (elem, text, html) {

       // `this` refers to inlineEdit instance plugin
       // `elem` is the currently edited element

       const c_id = $(elem).attr("data-cid");
       alert(c_id);  // 14756
    }
});
```

That plugin is not performing in an expected "jQuery Plugin" way.
Usually properly written plugins should:

- bind all methods to the Element callee,
- (in case of Event methods) the first parameter should always refer to the original Event.

allowing a developer to reference it using the `this` keyword to get the native JS Element or either doing `$(this)` inside the exposed public Methods just like we're expected from *native* jQuery Methods, and to have accessible the Event (i.e: useful in case we use arrow functions to extract the `currentTarget` since the inexistence of `this` keyword)

```
$someElem.on('click', function(evt) {
  const $el = $(this); // what we're used to
});

$someElem.on('click', (evt) => {
  const $el = $(evt.currentTarget); // the importance of always passing the Event as first param
});
```

clearly not implemented in that *plugin*.

Comment: I changed my code according to your recommendation and now I get the ID. That's great, thank you very much! Your explanations are also helpful.

Comment: @RalfZosel you're very welcome. PS: https://github.com/faulker/jqInlineEdit/issues/1

Comment: Thanks to your help jqInlineEdit works, but unfortunately only as long as I use IDs as a selector like `$("#remark1").inlineEdit …`. With classes like `$(".remark").inlineEdit …` and more than one text, it get confused and always opens the last entry. I guess it's a result of the issue you described above. I found another script which works fine in any case, but there, I have a very similar problem. I think, I will describe that in a separate post.

Comment: This is the new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62248536/inline-editing-of-textarea-with-jquery-inline-edit-js-get-the-id-and-save