# Inline Editing of Textarea with jquery.inline-edit.js – Get the id and save

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am looking for a simple way to implement inline editing in a table (with Django). I did not test stuff like [Django-Front](https://pypi.org/project/django-front/) or [django-inlineedit](https://pypi.org/project/django-inlineedit/) so far. I already found out, that not all simple solutions work for me. [jqInlineEdit](https://github.com/faulker/jqInlineEdit) and inline-edit.jquery.js do work only with *unique* selectors, [as I described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62245361/inline-editing-of-textarea-how-to-get-the-id#comment110091151_62245589).

With [jQuery.editable](http://shokai.github.io/jQuery.editable/) (jquery.inline-edit.js), I do not have these problems, but I do not know how to get the id and save the data.

```
<div id="remark4" class="editable" data-cid="4">Test #4</div>
<div id="remark5" class="editable" data-cid="5">Test #5</div>
<div id="remark6" class="editable" data-cid="6">Test #6</div>

<script src="file:jquery.inline-edit.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.remark').inlineEdit('click', {

        // use textarea instead of input field
        type: 'textarea',
        // attributes for input field or textarea
        attributes: {
            id: $(this).attr("data-cid"),
            class: 'input-class-1 input-class-2 input-class-3',
            style: 'background:#ffe;'
        }
    });
</script>
```

Is the `$(this).attr("data-cid")` part correct?  How can I run a let's say `alert(c_id + content)` after the content in the form has changed? I did not found a documentation or an example for that and trial and error was not successful so far.

**Followup:**

The docu does give [examples](http://shokai.github.io/jQuery.editable/). Incredible that I did not see this earlier, sorry for that.

I tried the following code instead of the one above:

```
    var option = { trigger: $(".editable"), action: "click" };
    $(".editable").editable(option, function (e) {
        alert(e.value);
    });
```

This is the error message: `TypeError: $(...).editable is not a function`

What's still wrong?

Comment: By reading the plugin documentatin I've seen there's an onEdit Method. You could use that method to set the desired ID from data-id

Comment: The `this` inside your `attributes` Object is actually `window`, not the actual Element you were wishing for.

Comment: May I ask, just to understand what you are building, you have a table (or DIVs) **inside a form**? And on submit you want to send the edited cells to the server for storage, right?

Comment: Right, it's a quite big table (with DIVs), but it's not inside a form. As soon as I am able to get this alert, I know what to do. I already have a dropdown in the table and this saves perfectly on change.

Comment: Also, why are you using `"click"` as the first plugin property? I don't think that plugin supports that String parameter..

Comment: PS https://github.com/faulker/jqInlineEdit/issues/2 I'd really suggest you to find another alternative - or rather to build your own! Should be pretty straightforward to make one.

Comment: In your followup edit `.editable` is yet another plugin, and you need to include it properly in your project, otherwise you'll get that error you mentioned.

Comment: have you ever considered this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable

Comment: Thank you for your tips and the hint with contentEditable. Yesterday I checked that a bit and contentEditable seemed to be a good candidate to build a proper solution with, which I wanted to attack later, but this morning I found your answer with the library and everything and all my problems where solved. You are the best! Thank you so much!

Comment: Well, `contenteditable` is not always the best solution for every situation, that's why I was asking, for example it inherits HTMLEditable ExecCommands like i.e: CTRL+B, CTRL+I etc (making a highlighted text bold, italic etc) also it allows the Enter key to introduce tags like `p` or `div` - It can be handled, but needs more coding. I gave you an example - if it fits that's great, otherwise a variant that uses `textarea` or `input` could work as well, but with a slightly different code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I may suggest an alternative using [**HTMLElement.contentEditable API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable).

```js
$("[data-cid]").prop({tabindex: 1, contenteditable: true}).on({

  focusin() {
    this.__html = $(this).html(); // Store current HTML content
  },
  
  focusout() {
  
    const data = {
      cid: this.dataset.cid,
      html: this.innerHTML,
    };
    
    if (this.__html === data.html) return;  // Nothing has changed.
    
    console.log(data); // Something changed, send data to server.
  }
  
})
```

```html
<div data-cid="4">Test #4</div>
<div data-cid="5">Test #5</div>
<div data-cid="6">Test #6</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

## Make your own library

Here's an example how you can simply create your own reusable function:

```js
// Editable
function Editable(sel, options) {
  if (!(this instanceof Editable)) return new Editable(...arguments); 
  
  const attr = (EL, obj) => Object.entries(obj).forEach(([prop, val]) => EL.setAttribute(prop, val));

  Object.assign(this, {
    onStart() {},
    onInput() {},
    onEnd() {},
    classEditing: "is-editing", // added onStart
    classModified: "is-modified", // added onEnd if content changed
  }, options || {}, {
    elements: document.querySelectorAll(sel),
    element: null, // the latest edited Element
    isModified: false, // true if onEnd the HTML content has changed
  });

  const start = (ev) => {
    this.isModified = false;
    this.element = ev.currentTarget;
    this.element.classList.add(this.classEditing);
    this.text_before = ev.currentTarget.textContent;
    this.html_before = ev.currentTarget.innerHTML;
    this.onStart.call(this.element, ev, this);
  };
  
  const input = (ev) => {
    this.text = this.element.textContent;
    this.html = this.element.innerHTML;
    this.isModified = this.html !== this.html_before;
    this.element.classList.toggle(this.classModified, this.isModified);
    this.onInput.call(this.element, ev, this);
  }

  const end = (ev) => {
    this.element.classList.remove(this.classEditing);
    this.onEnd.call(this.element, ev, this);
  }

  this.elements.forEach(el => {
    attr(el, {tabindex: 1, contenteditable: true});
    el.addEventListener("focusin", start);
    el.addEventListener("input", input);
    el.addEventListener("focusout", end);
  });

  return this;
}

// Use like:
Editable(".editable", {
  onEnd(ev, UI) { // ev=Event UI=Editable this=HTMLElement
    if (!UI.isModified) return; // No change in content. Abort here.
    const data = {
      cid: this.dataset.cid,
      text: this.textContent, // or you can also use UI.text
    }
    console.log(data); // Submit your data to server
  }
});
```

```css
/* Your styles */
.editable { 
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* this class is handled by Editable */
.is-modified { 
  background: #bff;
}

/* this class is handled by Editable */
.is-editing { 
  background: #bfb;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="editable" data-cid="4">Test #4</div>
<div class="editable" data-cid="5">Test #5</div>
<div class="editable" data-cid="6">Test #6</div>
<div class="editable" data-cid="7">Test #7</div>
```

### Editable *Function*:

> `Editable("selector", options);`
>   Returns: the Editable instance

### Options Object:

> #### Properties:
>
> `classEditing:`
>    **String** - Class to be added on focusin (Default: `"is-editing"`)
>
> `classModified:`
>   **String** - Class to be added on focusout if content has changed (Default: `"is-modified"`)
>
> #### Methods:
>
> `onStart(event, UI)`
>   **Function** - Triggers on `"focusin"` Event
>   Param: `event` the Event that triggered the callback
>   Param: `UI` the Editable instance Object
>   Bind: `this` is bound to the associated HTMLElement
>
> `onInput(event, UI)`
>   **Function** - Triggers on `"input"` Event
>   Param: `event` the Event that triggered the callback
>   Param: `UI` the Editable instance Object
>   Bind: `this` is bound to the associated HTMLElement
>
> `onEnd(event, UI)`
>   **Function** - Triggers on `"focusout"` Event
>   Param: `event` the Event that triggered the callback
>   Param: `UI` the Editable instance Object
>   Bind: `this` is bound to the associated HTMLElement
>
> #### Param `UI` (Editable instance) properties:
>
> `text` **String** - The currently edited element's textContent
>   `html` **String** - The currently edited element's innerHTML
>   `text_before` **String** - The element's textContent before the edit
>   `html_before` **String** - The element's innerHTML before the edit
>   `isModified` **Boolean** - `true` if innerHTML is not equal to the original
>   `elements` - static (not live) NodeList of Elements
>   `element` - The latest edited HTMLElement

Comment: You are awesome! Your code works like a charm. It is way more than I ever expected to get as help on stackoverflow. Thank yo so much! It's not only a very concrete support for me, but also a huge motivation for my further coding experience. I've learned a lot by our conversation. I spent a lot of time in checking these different approaches for inline editing but your code is so much better. Others will certainly also benefit by it.

Comment: @roko-c-buljan , Just came across this solution and very nice work. I was wondering if that approach can be applied to an entire form instead of individual elements. I am trying to achieve here https://codepen.io/saidcc/pen/JjrZegb?editors=1111 but have limited JS skills as you will see. I was trying to avoid contenteditable because its usually includes html as well if any copy paste, which is why i opted for input. Not the best approach prob. You may have a better approach. Thanks before hand

Comment: @Said and what is your problem with that demo? I like it, seems to work fine.

Comment: @roko-c-buljan, thanks for the feedback. I'm haven't figured out how to cancel an edit if it has not been saved therefore, reverting to original values. I think the code is also very basic and works only based on hardcoded values instead of more generic more specifically, the fields, have not figured out how to make it more dynamic.